# RDP connections very slow after update to Windows 8.1

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-8.1

Since I updated to Windows 8.1 (Enterprise) I have a sporadic issue with RDP connections. They're very slow. So it looks like the the machine runs at 100% with a high ping. But it's not.

The host itself is irrelevant in this case, whether it's Server 2012 or Server 2003. Having a look in the task manager, no process runs at 100% CPU nor consumes all the memory.

To workaround this issue, I'm running a Windows 7 VM and connect via RDP through this machine.

The problem is, I can't really reproduce the problem. My colleague has this issue in the office and at the customer's network. I just had it while being at two different customers.

We use TrendMicro OfficeScan which I thought might be the problem, but after disabling it, the problem persists.

Comment: So, this issue still persists. I disabled TrendMicro, played around with all the tips regarding auto-network-configuration which a lot of people mentioned on forums etc. -> nothing happened.

Comment: Try to Run as Administrator in Command Prompt : `netsh interface tcp set global autotuning=disabled`. You might need to do that on both client and server. You could also in the RDP Options, "Experience" tab, adjust the Performances settings. Have you also fully patched Windows 8.1 including optional Windows Updates (except Bing)?

Comment: That's what I was talking about, when I wrote "auto-network-configuration". Doing this on a server is not really an option, since the issue occurs with a few customer's servers. Yes, the system is up to date.

Comment: (1) There are several solutions mentions in [this thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/e862b4a9-0613-4054-9e4f-ce7ee99ebec9/windows-8-slow-doing-rdp?forum=w8itprogeneral) - see if any of them helps. (2) You could also try to install the Windows 7 network adapter driver in Windows 8 (rollback if problem). (3) Try disabling/enabling Desktop Composition and Visual Styles and also Windows standard/basic themes. (4) Ensure that local and remote desktop color depths are the same. Note: You might have differing results for servers 2012 and 2003.

Comment: In my opinion, RDP 7.1 in Windows 7 was the last decent RDP version, but I don't think it's an option in Windows 8.1. I never tried it, but you could copy mstsc.exe and mstscax.dll from Windows 7 to system32 on Windows 8.1, then do `regsvr32 C:\Windows\System32\mstscax.dll`. Take backups.

Comment: I'll try those things, when I get back to the customer and let you know, whether it worked or not. Thanks so far!

Comment: "The host itself is irrelevant in this case, whether it's Server 2012 or Server 2003." -- Um .... no. In fact, that may just be the **MOST** important factor there is. If your host doesnt support multiple monitors (because of version-mismatch) - that wont work. If your host doesnt support adaptive bandwidth-assignment - that wont work. If your host has a too old version of RDP (server 2003, for example) ... you will run into problems.

Answer (score 3):

Things to try :

1. Fully patch Windows 8.1 including optional Windows Updates (except Bing).
2. Disable TCP/IP auto-tuning by entering in Command Prompt that is Run as Administrator:
   `netsh interface tcp set global autotuning=disabled`
3. In the RDP Options, Experience tab, adjust the Performances settings.
4. Turn off [Scalable Networking Pack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Networking_Pack) with this registry hack :
   `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters]`
   `EnableTCPChimney=dword:00000000`
   `EnableTCPA=dword:00000000`
   `EnableRSS=dword:00000000`
   Export the old settings of this key as backup.
5. Try disabling/enabling Desktop Composition, Visual Styles and Windows Standard/Basic themes. This might work differently with Server 2003 and 2012.
6. Ensure that local and remote desktop color depths are the same.
7. Lastly, it is my opinion that RDP 7.1 in Windows 7 was the last decent RDP version, but it's not an option in Windows 8.1. I never did it, but you could try to copy `mstsc.exe` and `mstscax.dll` from system32 in Windows 7 to Windows 8.1, then do :
   `regsvr32 C:\Windows\System32\mstscax.dll`.
   Take backups and create at least a system restore point before starting.

Comment: Sorry for that pretty late answer. I was at my customer yesterday. Nothing helped unfortunately. I replaced the .exe + .dll but it didn't start. Instead it prompted an error message telling me "can't find C:\windows\system32\<lang_name>\mstc.exe.mui". Since my windows is set to German and I copied the Binary from another German Windwos 7, I checked the "de" folder which contains the .exe.mui. Also copied the same file from Win7, to see, whether it fixes the issue: unfortunately not. Even copying it to en-US didn't help.

I guess, I have to file a ticket...

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same issue too - unloading the Trend Micro OfficeScan on the CLIENT did indeed solve the issue. Now I'm stuck at how to allow RDP connections on 3389 and mstsc in my environment

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem and unloading Trend OfficeScan resolved the issue. I will add an exception in the admin console to exclude RDP from being scanned in real time.

Comment: On the server or the client? Firewall enabled in the OfficeScan? Imho, that's not really an option, since malicious software could use it to bypass the firewall.

Comment: in actually professional environments, there is little need for AV-solutions. Maybe on all the desktops but thats it for the most part. If you ACTUALLY need AV on servers ... well ... you did something horribly, horribly wrong in your company